# Python SpaCy .similarity providing unexpected results

Tags: python, spacy

I'm trying to test similarity of phrases using SpaCy, but I'm getting unexpectedly high similarity scores for phrases that should not be similar. For example if I run:

```
import spacy

# Load the spaCy model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

# Create Doc objects for the two strings
doc1 = nlp("Can I buy it at Walmart?")
doc2 = nlp("I like turtles")

print(doc1.vector_norm)

# Compute the similarity score between the two docs
similarity_score = doc1.similarity(doc2)

print(similarity_score)
```

I get 0.6934801627436817 as a result. This seems much too high to me, especially because ChatGPT generated this code for me and gave a result of ~0.30 when it ran the code. I'm using SpaCy v3.1.2 and en_core_web_md v3.1.0 (same as ChatGPT was using).

Any idea what could cause the results to be different?